# .NET Executing function in main thread(UI) from other thread

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

My application receive some commands from h/w devices in a Thread other than Main(UI) thread.

```
// start receiver-thread
m_recThread = new Thread(RecThread) { Name = "RS" };
```

from this thread i want to do some action on the UI Theraad. say one button click!!! i am using

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
  new Action<Vote>(StartThisVote), presidentvote);
```

but this didnot worked. please let me know who can execute a Command in Main Thread(UI) from this background thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "This didn't work..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a background thread, the [`CurrentDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher.aspx) will be null. You need to use the dispatcher associated with the UI that you want to modify. If you don't have access to the control itself from the thread code, you could pass the dispatcher in directly when you start the thread. (Assuming you're on the UI thread when you start the secondary thread.)

As noted in comments, assuming you've just got the one dispatcher (which is very likely) you could use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to access it anywhere. (It's harder to test via this static approach, but it's easy to code...)

Alternatively, if you're using C# 5 and .NET 4.5, I'd recommend that you look into async methods, which make a lot of this simpler.

Comment: You should also be able to access the Dispatcher by `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.